# Background rsync and pid from a shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, rsync

I have a shell script that does a backup. I set this script in a cron but the problem is that the backup is heavy so it is possible to execute a second rsync before the first ends up. 
I thought to launch rsync in a script and then get PID and write a file that script checks if the process exist or not (if this file exist or not). 
If I put rsync in background I get the PID but I don't know how to know when rsync ends up but, if I set rsync (no background) I can't get PID before the process finish so I can't write a file whit PID.

I don't know what is the best way to "have rsync control" and know when it finish.

***My script***

```
#!/bin/bash
pidfile="/home/${USER}/.rsync_repository"

if [ -f $pidfile ];
then
        echo "PID file exists " $(date +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
else
        rsync -zrt --delete-before /repository/ /mnt/backup/repositorio/ < /dev/null &
        echo $$ > $pidfile
        # If I uncomment this 'rm' and rsync is running in background, the file is deleted so I can't "control" when rsync finish
        # rm $pidfile 
fi
```

Can anybody help me?!

Thanks in advance !! :)

Comment: @user2181624 I don't know how much time I have to wait :S I think is not the best way.

Comment: you don't need to know how much time to wait.  see the bash man page (as it is so long, (and the word wait appears a gazillion times) go to the end of the man page, search backwards for 'SHELL BUILTIN' and then search forwards for 'wait'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# check to make sure script isn't still running
# if it's still running then exit this script

sScriptName="$(basename $0)"

if [ $(pidof -x ${sScriptName}| wc -w) -gt 2 ]; then 
    exit
fi
```

- pidof finds the pid of a process
- -x tells it to look for scripts too
- ${sScriptName} is just the name of the script...you can hardcode this
- wc -w returns the word count by words
- -gt 2 no more than one instance running (instance plus 1 for the pidof check)
- if more than one instance running then exit script

Let me know if this works for you.

Answer (score 1):

Test both for presence of pid file and status of the running process like this:

```
 #!/bin/bash

 pidfile="/home/${USER}/.rsync_repository" 
 is_running =0

 if [ -f $pidfile ];
 then
    echo "PID file exists " $(date +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    previous_pid=`cat $pidfile`
    is_running=`ps -ef | grep $previous_pid | wc -l` 
 fi

 if [ $is_running -gt 0 ]; 
 then
    echo "Previous process didn't quit yet"
 else
    rsync -zrt --delete-before /repository/ /mnt/backup/repositorio/ < /dev/null &
    echo $$ > $pidfile
 fi
```

Hope this helps!!!

Comment: Sounds good but I don't understand how the script knows when the process finish up. 
The script looks for a PID but it does not delete PID file so always it is going to be running, don't it? Thanks !

Comment: @jask the script does not wait for process to end. However, trick here is to record the PID of last started script process and on subsequent runs, just check the existence of last recorded PID (ps -ef | grep $previous_pid | wc -l). If the last process is still running, script exits without starting a new one, otherwise a new script is started and its PID is recorded.